# Valgrind reports a memory leak when defining a char* array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have another valgrind error that I can't seem to figure out. I have some code that loads a script then uses strtok() to tokenize the data in said script that has been loaded into a buffer. I allocate memory on the heap for my buffer using the following:

```
char *pPngStr = new char[4096];
```

Then at the end of the function, I free the memory using:

```
delete[] pPngStr;
```

Valgrind reports the allocation as so:

```
173 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3,753 of 4,627
```

Valgrind also reports the line where I free the memory as:

```
Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
```

This is all in the same function is the variable is local to only that function and not the class. I am at a loss as to how valgrind thinks that this is a memory leak. I am allocating all the memory I need then I am freeing it when I am done. I don't see what the problem is.

Here is the complete function (it may be a little messy):

```
void CSprite::LoadSprite()
{
FILE *pF = fopen("Data/Art/coin/coin.sprite", "rb");

if(!pF)
{
    return;
}

fseek(pF, 0, SEEK_END);
int length = ftell(pF);
fseek(pF, 0, SEEK_SET);

char *aData = new char[length];

fread(aData, 1, length, pF);

CheckGLError();

/**
  * The scripts are setup like so:
  ***********************************************
  * Pngs:
  * 4; // This is the number of frames.
  * <pngname>_001.png;
  * <pngname>_002.png;
  * <pngname>_003.png;
  * <pngname>_004.png;
  *
  * Properties:
  * name=<obj name>;
  * width=###;
  * height=###;
  * framerate=0.### // rate in seconds
  ************************************************
  */

mpSprite = new SGfxSprite;

char *pPngStr = new char[4096];
pPngStr = strtok(aData, "\n");

pPngStr = strtok(NULL, "\n");
int iNumFrames = atoi(pPngStr);
mpSprite->numFrames = iNumFrames;

mpSprite->textures = new GLuint[iNumFrames];
glGenTextures(iNumFrames, mpSprite->textures);

int i = 0; // used for loop only!
while(pPngStr != NULL)
{
    pPngStr = strtok(NULL, "\n");

    if(!strcmp(pPngStr, "Properties:") || i >= iNumFrames)
    {
        break;
    }

    if(mpPng->LoadPng(pPngStr))
    {
        CheckGLError();

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mpSprite->textures[i]);
        CheckGLError();

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        CheckGLError();

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        CheckGLError();

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
        CheckGLError();

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
        CheckGLError();

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);
        CheckGLError();

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, mpPng->miWidth, mpPng->miHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mpPng->mpData);
        CheckGLError();
    }

    ++i;
}

pPngStr = strtok(NULL, "=\n");
pPngStr = strtok(NULL, "\n");
mpSprite->name = pPngStr;

pPngStr = strtok(NULL, "=\n");
pPngStr = strtok(NULL, "\n");
mpSprite->width = atoi(pPngStr);

pPngStr = strtok(NULL, "=\n");
pPngStr = strtok(NULL, "\n");
mpSprite->height = atoi(pPngStr);

pPngStr = strtok(NULL, "=\n");
pPngStr = strtok(NULL, "\n");
mpSprite->framerate = (atof(pPngStr) * 1000);

mpSprite->x = 0;
mpSprite->y = 0;

mpSprite->currentFrame = 0;
mpSprite->paintTimer = 0;

fclose(pF);

delete[] pPngStr, aData;
```

}

*PLEASE NOTE: this function contains OpenGL code and also invokes members from data structures that are not defined here. The code also compiles without any warnings or errors in Xubuntu 12.04 with g++ (gcc 4.6) using Qt Creator 2.4.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
char *pPngStr = new char[4096];
pPngStr = strtok(aData, "\n");
```

Just in the line after the new, you are forgetting about the pointer that you go and using the variable to store other data. No doubt that there is a memory leak.

Comment: Also important to note that `delete [] x, y` does not call `delete [] y`.  The comma operator doesn't work that way.

Comment: well, I fixed that line and Valgrind no longer reports a memory leak. It still tells me that `delete pPngStr` is invalid though. It also says `delete[] pPngStr` is invalid. Am I not supposed to clean that up?

Comment: when you mean "I fixed that line", did you find out that are many other lines that do exactly the same. In fact, what you should do is delete the memory assignment because you are just not using it anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

The line that you have:

> > ```
> > delete[] pPngStr, aData;
> > ```

does not do what you think it does.

Try this instead:

```
delete[] pPngStr;
delete[] aData;
```

**Note**: Until you fix the bug that SJuan76 identifies, my answer is moot.

Comment: +1 to you as well as SJuan, both fixes need to be implemented.